# Parallel vs Sequential http downloads; profile and benchmark

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency

I wish I had more time to do the benchmarking and testing on my own but, alas, clients want features. So, I would like the community's views on this subject.

Problem:
I got into an argument with a dev about parallelizing downloads. I am for, he is against.

His arguments:

- Won't be much of a speed improvement.
- Will use too much memory.
- Will be unstable.
- I don't wanna.

My arguments:

- Will be a huge speed improvement.
- We have enough memory.
- Use a stable tested gem like Typhoeus.
- You should.

In the end I told him he should benchmark and profile his code with and without parallel downloads so we can let the numbers decide for us. I tested this on my end and saw ~300% improvement in execution time with 3 downloads but, I did not profile the code to see how much more memory it uses.

Use case: downloading up to 100s of HTML files.

My naive solution (Ruby 2.0):

```
require 'open-uri'
urls = ["up to hundreds of urls", ...]
max_threads = 20
threads = []
files = []
start_time = Time.now.to_f

urls.each do |url|
  threads << Thread.new do
    files << open(url)
  end
  threads.pop.join while threads.size >= max_threads
end
threads.map &:join

puts "done in #{Time.now.to_f - start_time}"
```

1. What are the possible problems with this code?
2. How should I decide on a value for `max_threads`?
3. How do I profile this to compare memory usage?
4. What are some recommended libraries to use for parallel downloads? Is Typhoeus good? Peach?
5. Does this even really matter on Ruby 2.0? Should I try JRuby? (My understanding is that even MRI will see improvements when using multithreading when the work being done in the thread is blocking IO: the thread sleeps, others get scheduled in, and indeed it did in my naive test)
6. Is parallelizing downloads in this simple use case a good idea? Why/why not?

Finally, when do you decide to parallelize work and what is your approach?

Comment: It seems like a large contributing factor will be the kind of network you're on, and the average file size. If you're requesting lots and lots of small files over a high-latency high-bandwidth network, then I'd imagine parallelizing will help a lot. If you're downloading lots of multi-megabyte files over a low latency network, then in theory it won't make much difference. It also depends on the remote server(s) - if all your URL's are on the same server, it might only allow say 6 concurrent connections, so if you have more than that many threads, there's no point

Comment: I assume you are downloading those HTML files from a public server somewhere on the internet. Note that browsers restrict the number of parallel downloads to 2 per server. Implementing a more greedy solution might not be liked by the server admins (again, assuming public server). Admins could limit your bandwidth or even ban your IPs.

Comment: It's one of our S3 buckets.